# Problem with Ubuntu windows. Thick Color Noise border

Tags: nvidia, graphics

Random Color Noise Border Ubuntu 16
I am getting a noise border on my Ubuntu 16 machine. Any ideas?

[image: Noise Border around everything...]

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bug with nvidia's latest proprietary drivers. See the linked question above for some possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this after wakeup forn suspend, please check this question: [Multicolor barcodes around windows and context menus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897022/multicolor-barcodes-around-windows-and-context-menus/897039#897039)