# Cannot change nvidia driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers, apt, nvidia, graphics

On Ubuntu 16.04, I initially had the nvidia-375 driver installed. However, this was giving me some strange pixelated borders on windows, as in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887933/weird-pixelated-white-border-ubuntu-xenial-16-04/889101#889101).

So, I followed the instruction from the top answer, which involved deleting all nvidia drivers, and then installing the nvidia-367 driver. To do this, I first ran 'sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*'. After checking "Additional Drivers" in "Ubuntu Software Centre", I noticed that there were no longer nvidia drivers, as expected. Then, I ran 'sudo apt-get install nvidia-367'.

However, after this, the pixelated borders still remained. I checked "Additional Drivers" in "Ubuntu Software Centre", and there were now two drivers installed: nvidia-375 and nvidia-340. But I only asked my system to install nvidia-367...

So, why did it install these two additional drivers, and not the one I requested it to install? Neither of these two drivers seem to solve the problem with the pixelated borders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colored borders around windows after update](http://askubuntu.com/questions/896529/colored-borders-around-windows-after-update)

Answer (score 0):

Now there is no the `367` Nvidia driver in Ubuntu repos.

The `nvidia-367` package still exists, but it points to `nvidia-375`.

A possible option is to install `nvidia-367` from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`, but since there is a "newer" package in the official repos, you will need to use Synaptic to pick a version.