# Weird pixels showing where window controls should be after suspend

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

Was doing some development using a Java library and started getting a buffer overflow error that I thought was being caused by an Nvidia driver update so I started fooling around with those a bit and now I've got an odd error that shows up.  Basically if I put my computer into suspended mode (running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), I have the following odd pixel stuff showing up:

[image]

As you can see, this could prove rather annoying.  The problem doesn't appear if I have the windows in full screen mode, only in windowed mode.  I've tried running a purge on the nvidia stuff and reinstalling the nvidia-375 package as well as going into the addition drivers option and trying different items listed there.  However, nothing appears to be working.  There's also a problem where opening anything new freezes the monitor where it opens.  I'm at a loss of what else to do about this so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And also if this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/896529/colored-borders-around-windows-after-update

Comment: I will check them out and comment if they don't work.  Thanks for the heads up about the duplicate